# How to return empty cells for repeated values and keep only the cells which are different?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

I have a query that selects some fields to display from a table

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 FROM table1
```

I want instead of returning :

[alt text http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/3455/87921605.png](http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/3455/87921605.png)

To return:

[alt text http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/3921/85722509.png](http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/3921/85722509.png)

How could I modify my SQL statement to return the second figure ?
Or at least how to change the gridview properties of .Net to do so (if this is possible) ?

Comment: not everyone can see your images, "network police" like to filter imageshack

Comment: Thanks KM for this important note, would you advice me with another free file uploading hosting to use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a common table expression (`WITH`), a self-join, and the `ROW_NUMBER` and `NULLIF` functions.

```
WITH t AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Field1) rownum FROM table1)
SELECT NULLIF(curr.Field1, prev.Field1) Field1,
       NULLIF(curr.Field2, prev.Field2) Field2,
       NULLIF(curr.Field3, prev.Field3) Field3
FROM t curr
LEFT OUTER JOIN t prev ON prev.rownum = curr.rownum - 1
```